# How do I remove characters between /* and */ from a string

Tags: java, remove-method

I am trying to remove characters of comments(/* */) from the String s, but I am not sure how I extract them, especially, from the second comment.
This is my code:

```
public String removeComments(String s)
{
    String result = "";
    int slashFront = s.indexOf("/*");
    int slashBack = s.indexOf("*/");
    
    if (slashFront < 0) // if the string has no comment
    {
        return s;
    }
    // extract comment
    String comment = s.substring(slashFront, slashBack + 2);
    result = s.replace(comment, "");
    return result;
    }
```

In tester class:

```
System.out.println("The hippo is native to Western Africa. = " + tester.removeComments("The /*pygmy */hippo is/* a reclusive*/ /*and *//*nocturnal animal */native to Western Africa."));
```

output: `The hippo is/* a reclusive*/ /*and *//*nocturnal animal */native to Western Africa. // expected: The hippo is native to Western Africa.`

As you can see, I can not remove comments but the first one.

Comment: You have to put the indexOf methods in a loop, exiting the loop when the slashFront is less than zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a one-liner:

```
public String removeComments(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("/\\*.*?\\*/", "");
}
```

This caters for any number of comments, including zero.

Comment: Prefix the regular expression with `(?s)` if the comment can contain newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the index of both String, convert it to a StringBuilder  and use method deleteCharAt(int index).